# First played sound in a game produced by Spritekit on real device is very low?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am simulating my game on my iPad Air iOS 9.1 produced using XCode 7.3 beta and Swift 2.2 Spritekit 
I am using sounds via

```
SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(_: string)
```

whenever I start the game for the first time ; including going home screen then back to game ; the first played audio is very low or seems destructed.
Also I tried simulating premade games by other developers having the same problem .

Maybe a bug of the beta version of Xcode ?

Comment: Can you provide more context ... What type of audio file you use ? Add some more code. I can't reproduce what you are saying (I am on Xcode 7.1.1 though).

Comment: I am using .wav sound formats .
Code is not the issue , I've tried other pretested projects.
I am using a beta version of Xcode 7.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple low-latency audio playback in iOS Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680007/simple-low-latency-audio-playback-in-ios-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with `SKAction` but you can use `prepareToPlay()` on `viewDidLoad` or `AppDelegate` then you can play it when you need it.

- Also, the **m4a** format will be faster than **mp3**.

You can find full code example in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34981944/2125010

Comment: He is using `SKAction.playeSoundFileNamed()` not `AVAudioPlayer`, so there is no [prepare](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioEngine_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioEngine/prepare) method in that case (if that is what you've meant).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Playing silent sound when game becomes active resolves that.

Comment: I thought of that at first , but I think we should look for a cure not a symptomatic relief .