# Simultaneously playing the same sound

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

In my game, I need to play a sound effect and there will be occasions where multiple instances of the exact same sound effect will need to play simultaneously, say, 10 phones ringing nearly at the same time.
I could make one instance of `AVAudioPlayer` every time the sound needs to play, but I am worried by the delay it might add before playing, and it just doesn't feel like the right solution...

Is there some API made especially for that that I could use ?

Thank you.

Comment: I actually wrote a class for a question with the same requirement. Just a sec

Comment: Hi Trevor did you check answer on another question which might be similar to this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28313535/2618600

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865233/get-avaudioplayer-to-play-multiple-sounds-at-a-time

Comment: It's not in swift 3 though so you might need to change some syntax

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson Thank you, I did thought about making multiple instances of AVAudioPlayer, but I was wondering if, since it's the same sounds that needs to play, there would be a better solution than to make multiple instances of AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Sadly that's not possible, it would stop the previous sound

Comment: @Nitya I had found it by searching for my question, but that's no exactly what I want to do... I was wondering there wouldn't be some better, more efficient solution than to just make multiple instance of AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: maybe better use AudioUnit framework for that. https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiounit

Comment: Yeah audio unit would work. Using AVAudioPlayer kind of limits your options.

Comment: @Yuri Thank you ! Didn't knew about it ! Looks like it is still using some C code ?

Comment: @OlivierWilkinson Thank you !

Comment: @Trevör Anne Denise i do not know about C code, but it works great for multiple sound tracks playing at the same time.

Comment: No problem at all :)